# Java-Spring-JUnit5-Mockito Test Setup

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I am trying to set up a testing environment using an expectedPojo, but I continue getting the error that the constructor is undefined. From the error, I see it is listing the LocalTimeDate in the expectedPojo as String which may be the cause, but I am unfamiliar with testing with a LocalDateTime entry.

```java
public class UserPojo {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean darkModePreference;
    private LocalDateTime registerDate;
    private int roleId;

    public UserPojo() {
    }

    public UserPojo(int id, String name, String email, String phoneNumber, String username, String password,
            boolean darkModePreference, LocalDateTime registerDate, int roleId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.darkModePreference = darkModePreference;
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
```

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class LoginAndRegisterTest {
    
    @Mock
    UserDao userDao;
    
    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;
    
    private UserPojo expectedPojo;
    private UserEntity dummyEntity;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        LocalDateTime now;
        expectedPojo = new UserPojo(1, "Goldendeep", "golden@coolkids.com", "333-343-3434", "golden", "kaur11", false, "2022-06-25T22:37:24.894", 2);
        dummyEntity = new UserEntity(1, "Goldendeep", "golden@coolkids.com", "333-343-3434", "golden", "kaur11", false, "2022-06-25T22:37:24.894", 2);
    
    }
```

Comment: "The constructor UserPojo(int, String, String, String, String, String, boolean, String, int) is undefined"

Comment: Use `LocalDateTime.parse("...")` for the second-to-last argument.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the object of UserPojo class you are passing the second-to-last argument as String instead an argument of LocalDateTime type is expected, which is causing the issue. Either provide the argument of LocalDateTime type or modify the constructor definition to accept String argument.

Comment: Yes, I looked up an example of a LocalDateTime output which is what I inputted in the string. Rob Spoor's suggestion was an easy fix for the error. I will be continuing the JUnit test with the given and expected return pojo. Thank you for your input.